# Using Python and Flask. What is this line mean in my HTML?

Tags: python, html, web, flask

I'm following a flask tutorial online and I've seen these lines twice now. I pointed an arrow in my image to show what I'm referring to

[image]

Comment: That's a regular character which will appear on the page between the links.

Comment: Could you give an example or a link to the meaning? Sorry I don't really know what you mean since the second image isn't between a link but in the beginning of one

Comment: That means that the character will appear before the link.  It's no different from writing `abc`.

Comment: It's just a *"pipe"* `|`, used as a visual separator between the different links - *look at the rendered output*.

Comment: ahh ok so it's just plain text. lol thanks. I thought it was something complicated